# Personalization of Pycharm debugger panel

Tags: pycharm

Is it possible to personalize the debugging panel in Pycharm so that when I debug a script, the debugger goes directly to Console tab with Python prompt instead of the Debugger tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial answer is that it is possible to pin the Console tab with the "pin icon" at the bottom.

[image]